# Javascript probability

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a realistic unbiased JavaScript dice using Math random object. I want a number from 2-12 to appear on the webpage when I click but it doesn't return. What is wrong with my code.

```
<html>
<head><title>DiceBoy</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function getRandom(){
  var num=Math.random();
  if(num < 0.0278) return 2; 
  else if(num < 0.0834) return 3;
  else if(num < 0.1667) return 4; 
    else if(num < 0.2778) return 5; 
      else if(num < 0.4167) return 6; 
        else if(num < 0.5834) return 7; 
          else if(num < 0.7223) return 8;
            else if(num < 0.8334) return 9; 
              else if(num < 0.9167) return 10; 
                else if(num < 0.9723) return 11;
                  else return 12;
                  var x=getRandom();
                  document.write(x);
}

</script>

<input type="button" value="Click Here" onClick="getRandom();">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `var x=getRandom();document.write(x);` put this outside of getrandom function

Comment: 1) You are creating a "deep recursion". 2) **Don't** use `document.write`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your return statments will exit the method when they are reached, and the rest of the code is not run. You also do not want to call your getRandom method from within the method, or you will have a never ending loop. Rather then returning the number (since no one is listening to the return value) store it in a variable and then use it in the last two lines.

```
function getRandom(){
  var num=Math.random();
  var result = 0;
  if(num < 0.0278) result = 2; 
  else if(num < 0.0834) result = 3;
    else if(num < 0.1667) result = 4; 
     .
     .
              else result =  12;
              document.write(result);
}
```

Comment: @AsmastasMaz Yuck. *What an icky "solution" this is*. A much better solution would be: `var result = getRandom(); document.write(result);` (and of course remove this code from inside the getRandom function). Instead you've now mixed up the data generation and the use.

Comment: @pst, I answered his question of "why didn't this work?" But your right, it's not the best way to actually do what he wants to do, it just shows him what he did wrong. AsmastasMaz, please do read the other answers, especially from pst and frenchie.

Answer (score 4):

Why not write it like this:

```
var RandomNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
var RandomNumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;

var DiceNumber = RandomNumber1 + RandomNumber2;
```

Comment: That's not the correct probabilities for a pair of dice. 7 is more likely than 2 or 12.

Comment: May I suggest `Math.floor()` instead of `parseInt()`?

Comment: @TildalWave: go to google and look at the formula for generating a random number between 2 numbers.

Comment: @TildalWave: I just put the whole thing in for the OP to get the concept. But yes, it comes down to (Math.random() * 6) and then you extract the int out of it.

Comment: Regarding the formula used here, it's generating a random number between 0 and 5, not between 1 and 6. You need to add 1 _after_ rounding down to the nearest integer.

Comment: ok, there it is; I think that's the final edit. I also changed parseInt to .floor();

Comment: @TildalWave: that hard fought:)

Comment: @TildalWave: nah, you don't play dice against God; he can make it come out whatever he needs to, no randomness for him:)!

Comment: I don't know how I didn't think of this simpler one. But anyways it's really hard to undo all the hard work i.e. how much time i spent on finding and adding up the probabilities

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>DiceBoy</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            function getRandom() {
                return (Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1) * 2;
            }
        </script>
        <input type="button" value="Click Here" onClick="document.write(getRandom());">
    </body>
</html>
```

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/kvFE5/1/

You should ideally refactor this to be handled [unobtrusively](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

Although honestly - why aren't you using the [Math.random](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that ..

```
var x=getRandom();
document.write(x);
```

*is never called* as the function "returns" before then. Move the code *outside* the function so that it can call the randomizing function and then use the result.

```
function getRandom () {
   // the long icky original code WITHOUT the following:
   // var x=getRandom();
   // document.write(x);
}
// later, OUTSIDE the function
var result = getRandom();
document.write(result);
```

However, a better way to get the same effect is to use:

```
function getDiceRole() {
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 2
}
```

---

For readers: as for why two rolls are needed, see [Statistics of Dice Roles](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/math/dice.html) - note how it is *not* an equal probability to get all the values. That is, a simple `Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) + 2` is *incorrect*.

> .. in the throw of two dice, the different possibilities for the total of the two dice are not equally probable because there are more ways to get some numbers than others.

Comment: His probabilities are not equal.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this to generate random number between two numbers

```
/**
 * Returns a random integer between min and max
 * Using Math.round() will give you a non-uniform distribution!
 */
function getRandomInt (min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

In your case call like

```
 getRandomInt (2, 12);
```

The full html will look like

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    /**
     * Returns a random integer between min and max
     * Using Math.round() will give you a non-uniform distribution!
     */
    function getRandomInt (min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }

    function generateNumber()
    {
       document.getElementById('generated-id').innerHTML = getRandomInt (2, 12);
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
Generated number : <span id="generated-id"></span>
<input type="button" onclick="generateNumber();" value="Generate random number" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's not correct for 2 dice, the probabilities are not equal.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry... I didn't get it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like his using the `Math.floor` which rounds a number downward to its nearest integer.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>DiceBoy</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="javascript/text">
            function getDieRoll() {
                return Math.floor(Math.random() * (12 - 1+ 1)) +1;
            }
        </script>
        <input type="button" value="Click Here" onClick="document.write(getDieRoll());">
    </body>
</html>
```